# Mysql Unique records, where multiple records exist

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with a Mysql call and was hoping to borrow your expertise.

I believe that what I want may only be possible using two selects and I have not yet done one of these and am struggling to wrap my head around this.

I have a table like so:

```
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
|      username    |       acctstarttime  |       acctstoptime            |
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
|      bill        |   22.04.2014         |            23.04.2014         |
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
|      steve       |   16.09.2014         |                               |
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
|      fred        |   12.08.2014         |                               |
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
|      bill        |   24.04.2014         |                               |
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I wish to select only unique records from the username column ie I only want one record for bill and I need the one with most recent start_date, providing they <strike>were</strike> weren't in the last three months (end_date is not important to me here) else I do not want any data. In summary I just need anyone where there most recent start date is over 3 months old.

The command I am using currently is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(username), ra.acctstarttime AS 'Last IP', ra.acctstoptime
FROM radacct AS ra
WHERE ra.acctstarttime < DATE_SUB(now(), interval 3 month)
GROUP BY ra.username
ORDER BY ra.acctstarttime DESC
```

However, this simply gives me details about the date_start for that particular customer where they had a start date over 3 months ago.
I have tired a few other combinations of this and have tried a command with a double select but I'm currently hitting brick walls. Any help or a push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

***Update***

I have created the following:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f47b2/1

Effectively I should only see 1 row when the query is as it should be. This would be the row for bill. As he is the only one that does not have a start date within the last three months. The result I would expect to see is the following:

```
24  bill    April, 11 2014 12:11:40+0000    (null)
```

As this is the latest start date for bill, but this start date is not within the last three months. Hopefully this will help clarify. Many thanks for your help thus far.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f47b2/14

This is another example. If the acctstartdate for bill would show as the April entry, then I could add my where clause for the last three months and this would give me my desired result.

Comment: You should reverse your comparison i.e.'WHERE ra.acctstarttime > DATE_SUB(now(), interval 3 month)'

Comment: @sqlab Please see the update in the question. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQLFiddle**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/444432/9 (MySQL 5.5)

I am looking at the question in 2 ways based on the current text:

`I only want one record for bill and I need the one with most recent start_date, providing they were in the last three months (end_date is not important to me here) else I do not want any data`

**Structure**

```
create table test
(
  username varchar(20),
  date_start date
);
```

**Data**

```
Username    date_start
---------   -----------
bill        2014-09-25
bill        2014-09-22
bill        2014-05-26
andy        2014-05-26
tim         2014-09-25
tim         2014-05-26
```

**What we want**

```
Username    date_start
---------   -----------
bill        2014-09-25
tim         2014-09-25
```

**Query**

```
select * 
from test a
inner join 
(
  select username, max(date_start) as max_date_start
  from test
  where date_start > date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)
  group by username
) b
on 
  a.username = b.username
  and a.date_start = b.max_date_start
where 
  date_start > date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)
```

**Explanation**

For the most recent last 3 months, let's get maximum start date for each user. To limit the records to the latest 3 months we use `where date_start > date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)` and to find the maximum start date for each user we use `group by username`.

We, then, join main data with this small subset based on user and max date to get the desired result.

**Another angle**

If we desire to NOT look at the latest 3 months and instead find the most recent date for each user, we would be looking at this kind of data:

**What we want**

```
Username    date_start
---------   -----------
bill        2014-05-26
tim         2014-05-26
andy        2014-05-26
```

**Query**

```
select * 
from test a
inner join 
(
  select username, max(date_start) as max_date_start
  from test
  where date_start < date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)
  group by username
) b
on 
  a.username = b.username
  and a.date_start = b.max_date_start
where 
  date_start < date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)
```

Hopefully you can change these queries to your liking.

**EDIT**

Based on your good explanation, here's the query
SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f47b2/17

```
select * 
from activity a

-- find max dates for users for records with dates after 3 months
inner join 
(
  select username, max(acctstarttime) as max_date_start
  from activity
  where acctstarttime < date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)
  group by username
) b
on 
  a.username = b.username
  and a.acctstarttime = b.max_date_start

-- find usernames who have data in the recent three months 
left join
(
    select username, count(*)
    from activity
    where acctstarttime >= date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)
    group by username
) c
on 
  a.username = c.username

where 
  acctstarttime < date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)
  -- choose users who DONT have data from recent 3 months
  and c.username is null
```

Let me know if you would like me to add explanation

Comment: Apologies I have corrected my question as there was a type ie "were" was meant to be "weren't". Please see the update in my question.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat `select date_sub(current_date, interval 3 month);` would be `June, 26 2014`. So any username with records after June, 26th should appear. In addition to bill (ID 24), IDs 13 and 26 should also appear. Is that correct?

Comment: No only Bill should appear as the other users in the table, Steve and Fred do have a date that is within the last three months. Fred for example has an entry after this date `July, 07 2014` and Steve has an entry also after this date `July, 11 2014`. So both have been active within the last three months. Bill however, does not have a start date that happens within the last three months and therefore this is what I will need to see, the people who have not been active for the last three months.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat Oh, you are right! Thank you for the explanation. Let me see what I can do

Comment: I have added another query here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f47b2/14 If I could get the row for Bill showing the date for April, then I could apply a WHERE statement and I would have the result I need.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat I have added an update that you can tweak http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f47b2/17

Comment: I have tested on a local db and changed Steve so that he also does not have a start date in the last three months and hey presto both Bill and Steve appear. This is exactly what I needed. A big big thank you, it would have taken me countless hours to arrive at this solution. Saved to my snippets, now I just need to read it and understand it. A tick and upvote for you. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat Great to hear it's working well for you. Good work with explaining the details. It was quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.*
  from radacct t
  join (  
        select ra.username, max(ra.acctstarttime) as acctstarttime
          from radacct as ra
         WHERE ra.acctstarttime < DATE_SUB(now(), interval 3 month)
       ) s on t.username = s.username and t.acctstarttime = s.acctstarttime
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e60d/3)

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me no result. I do have one record that has not had a start date within the last month, I have changed the date sub to show 1 week instead and the record is not showing.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e60d/3) what row do you need?